# Does the rogue's Reliable Talent feature apply to a harengon's initiative checks (thanks to the Hare-Trigger trait)?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, rogue, racial-traits, initiative

Rogues gain the [Reliable Talent](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/rogue#ReliableTalent-349) feature at level 11:

> By 11th level, you have refined your chosen skills until they approach perfection. Whenever you make an ability check that lets you add your proficiency bonus, you can treat a d20 roll of 9 or lower as a 10.

In addition, [Harengons](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/814914-harengon) have the [Hare-Trigger racial trait](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/814914-harengon#HarengonTraits):

> You can add your proficiency bonus to your initiative rolls.

As a level 11 harengon rogue, **do my initiative rolls benefit from the Reliable Talent feature?**

Answer (score 24):

### Yes, Reliable Talent applies to a harengon's initiative rolls

1. An [initiative](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Initiative) roll is a Dexterity ability check.
2. The [Harengon's Hare-Trigger racial trait](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/814914-harengon#HarengonTraits) allows you to add your proficiency bonus to your initiative rolls.

Since you can add proficiency bonus to your initiative roll, Reliable Talent does apply to your initiative roll.

Answer (score -3):

I would rule that no, it does not apply.

The first sentence of the description reads:

"By 11th level, you have refined your chosen skills until they approach perfection."

Therefore, it seems that RAI is that Reliable Talent only applies to skills, not all ability checks. Since Initiative is not a "chosen skill" I would rule that Reliable Talent does not apply to Initiative rolls.